# Chrome Extension fetch function not sending cookies

Tags: laravel, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that does an ajax call using the `fetch` function to my server running laravel.

manifest perfmissions

```
"permissions": [
  "webRequest",
  "webRequestBlocking",
  "webNavigation",
  "activeTab",
  "tabs",
  "cookies",
  "<all_urls>"
],
```

fetch call

```
fetch(this.url, {
  credentials: 'include',
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  body: encodeDataToURL(telemetry)
})
.then(function (data) {
  console.log('Request succeeded with JSON response', data);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log('Request failed', error);
});
```

Cookies

`siusession=eyJpdiI6InlRS2wyb1BCZnJSSGtUaXVRelV4M3c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiRThteUk4MmVxeXV6a1N5ZUxTaFpxcUtSazJQRE1ZUUNQUWlBREVTdHRQM2pjNEVJUVUxd3gwM1JZMDNjOXR2TyIsIm1hYyI6ImUwMGQyNmAAhwQ3YWQ4YzRhOWVhYTk2ZjI2NDgwNTljNDE2YWU5NTdlZWM1MThiZWJjYzI3NmZjZWRhOGRlMzIifQ%3D%3D; expires=Tue, 25-Sep-2018 04:28:56 GMT; Max-Age=28800; path=/; secure; httponly; samesite=lax`

I have a opened session on my browser to that domain, which makes me having cookies with the `Session ID` and `XSRF-TOKEN`.

The problem is, it doesn't send the cookies with the call.
And on firefox, the same exact code and manifest it does send the browser cookies with the call.

What can be wrong? Does chrome require some sort of different permissions or another way to make the call including cookies?

Comment: Try adding `mode: 'cors',` also make sure the cookie is set in Chrome, otherwise it might be a browser bug.

Comment: Did you already try XMLHttpRequest as suggested in this reported [issue](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/470) if you have problems when using native fetch in the browser?

Comment: yes,that's the question,
It will happen when your server address is local ip

Comment: @zeroonnet - Were you able to find the answer to this question? Kindly let us know. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Here is a related Chromium bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=617198

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the fetch call is made from the background script, you'll need to query the cookies and insert those in the http header.

Comment: I made the XMLHttpRequest from content script, still no luck. It's not working.